# Key difference between Hexagonal Architecture vs Clean Architecture?

Tags: architecture, clean-code, clean-architecture, hexagonal-architecture

I am trying to improve the architecture for my React app project that has grown in size lately.

I'm looking at [Hexagonal architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_architecture_(software)) and [Clean architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html), and I couldn't really see the difference between them.

In Hexagonal, there are main elements like  "entities -> port -> adapter".

In clean architecture, there are elements like ENTITIES -> USECASE (similar to adapter) -> INTERFACE (similar to port) and External

Is Clean architecture superset of Hexagonal, or they are different? If they are different, what makes them distinct from each other?

Comment: @DocBrown the article explains detail about clean architecture but didn't compare the difference to Hexagonal, it says "similar" means not same, whats the difference, if i were presuming Clean arh. == Hexagonal archm, then why Clean architecture exist if its just another name of hexagonal?  i'm still confused

Comment: Clarifications to a question should be edited into the question, not just in the comments. Questions are way better received by the community when askers show us their prior research, tell us what they found and why it did not meet their needs. And regarding your confusion: I will go and write a short answer.

Answer (score 7):

Bob Martin's [blog entry about Clean Architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) explains it in one sentence:

> "The diagram at the top of this article [Clean Architecture] is an attempt at integrating all these architectures [including Hexagonal Architecture] into a single actionable idea."

So "Clean Architecture" is not just "one architecture", it is collective term for several architectural variants, all sharing the same ideas, and Hexagonal is one of them. Maybe a more precise title for that blog post would have been "Clean Architecture**s**", but I guess Bob Martin favored something more striking like "The Clean Architecture" for self-marketing reasons. Hence, it is not surprising you don't see a lot differences between the two terms.

Comment: thanks! "it is collective term for several architectural variants, all sharing the same ideas, and Hexagonal is one of them" but this still means there gonna be a difference, i'm looking to identify the difference as part of my architecture study right now, or if clean architecture meant to improve Hexagonal, what are the features it improves?

Answer (score 1):

I too don't see the difference. Their goals are the same. To separate the interesting business logic from external dependencies, so the logic can be reasoned about and tested in isolation from those dependencies.

The only difference I can see is that hexagonal architecture focuses more on how the boundary between the core and external systems is implemented. While Clean architecture worries more that the separation exists in the first place, irrespective how the boundary is implemented. But I don't believe that is a useful distinction.

Comment: Thanks, after studying for a while it seems to be highly similar, but i don't understand why not just call it hexagonal then, i still on progress to study and identify the key difference, 
i learned that Alistair also contributes developing Clean architecture (i saw his name in Clean architecture book) 

but are those what things that Clean improved from hexagonal?